# Run a file automatically in terminal when you click on it

Tags: kali-linux, python, executable

I'm using  `Linux debian 4.9.0-kali4-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 4.9.30-1kali1 (2017-06-06) x86_64 GNU/Linux` and want to make `/home/pantheon/Desktop/pycrust-20170611-2151.sh` run in terminal when I klick on it. The file is written in python,

`#!/bin/env python
import os
os.system("cd /home/pantheon/Desktop/fluxion")
os.system("sudo ./fluxion")`

I have tried with

<s>`chmod +x /home/pantheon/Desktop/pycrust-20170611-2151.sh` and `chmod u+x <"">`</s>

To execute in terminal, `./home/pantheon/Desktop/pycrust-20170611-2151.sh`, which gives me the error 
`bash: ./home/pantheon/Desktop/pycrust-20170611-2151.sh: No such file or directory`.

`/home/pantheon/Desktop/pycrust-20170611-2151.sh` gives me the output
`bash: /home/pantheon/Desktop/pycrust-20170611-2151.sh: /bin/env: bad interpreter: No such file or directory`. (Overlined text as it is not what I want to do. I do not know about the errors, though).

I also have tried to tweak Nautilus, but that didn't help me either, as executing the file in terminal that way results in a `There was an error creating the child process for this terminal. Failed to execute child process "/home/pantheon/Desktop/pycrust-20170611-2151.py" (No such file or directory)`

I have done [this](https://askubuntu.com/a/38666/639879).

`sudo ls -l /home/pantheon/Desktop/pycrust-20170611-2151.sh` gives me the output `-rwxr-xr-x 1 pantheon pantheon 103 Jun 11 23:02 /home/pantheon/Desktop/pycrust-20170611-2151.sh`

I have looked on many other forums, but have not found an answer to my problem. I think the most easy thing to do is to just ask you for help. For example, I did either not understand or get any help from the following questions: [How to automatically “Run in Terminal” for script in CentOS linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/249745/how-to-automatically-run-in-terminal-for-script-in-centos-linux), https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19509911/how-to-make-python-script-executable-when-click-on-the-file, https://askubuntu.com/questions/138908/how-to-execute-a-script-just-by-double-clicking-like-exe-files-in-windows and so on.

I know, I can open terminal and just run it as a .py file, but that is not what I want to do. I want it to run automatically in the terminal when klicking on the .sh (or .py) file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
```

as your shebang (note the `/usr`).